# using object initializer to ButtonField

Tags: c#

My current code was as follows;

```
ButtonField DetailButton = new ButtonField();
DetailButton.CommandName = "Detail";
DetailButton.ControlStyle.CssClass = "buttonBlue";
```

After warning IDE0017 message, I changed it as follows
(IDE0017: Object initialization can be simplified)

```
ButtonField DetailButton = new ButtonField()
{
    CommandName = "Detail",
    ControlStyle.CssClass = "buttonBlue"
};
```

But now the following error occurred;
Error CS0103 The name 'ControlStyle' does not exist in the current context

I was able to fix the error as follows.
But I'm not sure it's the right solution.

```
ButtonField DetailButton = new ButtonField()
{
    CommandName = "Detail"
};

DetailButton.ControlStyle.CssClass = "buttonBlue";
```

I couldn't find any details about this on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers) syntax:

```
ButtonField DetailButton = new ButtonField
{
    CommandName = "Detail",
    ControlStyle = { CssClass = "buttonClue" }
};
```